# Compare array and change if values are different

Tags: javascript

I have the next situation in JavaScript:

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3];  // by default it is empty `[]`
const arr2 = [2,1,8,9];
```

`arr1` can be changed dynamicly. So sometimes it could be `[1,2,3,4]` or `[4,2,3]` and so on.

The idea is next:

Depending by the `arr1` to change the `arr2` like,
if in `arr1` is a number which is equal with a number from `arr2`,
then the number from `arr2` that is equal should be deleted,
but if the new number that is added in `arr1` is not exists in `arr2` then it should be added in `arr2`:
EX:

1. `arr1 = [];        arr2=[2,1,8,9]` // nothing happens
2. `arr1 = [1];       arr2=[2,8,9]`   // 1 from arr2 is deleted
3. `arr1 = [1,8,9,7]; arr2=[1,2,7]`   // 1,8,9 from arr2 is deleted, 7 is added

Comment: `arr1`  and / or `arr2` can be very big array  sized ( more than 1000 elements ? , 10000, 100000... ) ?

Comment: @MisterJojo, no

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain the logic.. for each elem in `arr1`, if `arr2` has the elem(`arr2.indexOf(a)!=-1`), run a while loop that will stop when ALL elems in `arr2` that match the specific elem in `arr1` are removed

Lastly the `else` logic would activate if arr2 **DOES NOT** contain specific elem

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3];  // by default it is empty `[]`
const arr2 = [2,1,8,9];

function updateArr(arr1,arr2){
  arr1.forEach(a=>{
    let index=arr2.indexOf(a)
    if(index!=-1){
      while(index!=-1){arr2.splice(index,1);index=arr2.indexOf(a)}
    }
    else{arr2.push(a)}
  })
  return arr2
}

//function that takes in 2 vars, uses the first to edit the second

console.log(updateArr([2,3,7,9], [2,1,8,9]))
console.log(updateArr(arr1,arr2))
console.log("No cap it works\n",arr2)
```

Comment: could you show also an example using react js hooks like `useState`, like const [arr2, setArr2] = useState([1,2,3]). How to change the state in this situation?

Comment: ok im gonna come clean with u.. i havent really learned react(secondary school year gonna be over soon so that gonna change) but I CAN make a function

Comment: could you help with the function?

Comment: oh.. just made a slight syntax error.. my bad.. check it now

Answer (score 0):

In a simple words, you want to keep only uniques elements of Arr1 and Arr2, and give the result in Arr2 (not in a new array)

```js
function updArr2(arr1, arr2)
  {
  let set1 = new Set(arr1)
    , plus = arr1.filter(x=>!arr2.includes(x))

  for(let i=arr2.length;i--;)  
    if (set1.has(arr2[i])) arr2.splice(i,1)

  plus.forEach(e => arr2.push(e) )
  }

const
  arr_1 = [1,2,3] 
, arr_2 = [2,1,8,9]
;
updArr2(arr_1, arr_2)


console.log( JSON.stringify(arr_2) )
```